# Increase caption size from kableExtra table in RMarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, kableextra

I'm using the `posterdown` package in R to generate a HTML Poster and render it as a PDF.

I have a table in my Rmd file, however the caption is really small. Is there a way to increase the size of the caption?

Secondly, I would also like to move the title and affiliation in the header slightly down (so that its more in the center of the header. Is there a way to do that?

Here is a snippet of my Rmd file

``````
---
title: Here is my title 
author:
  - name: Name and Surname
affiliation:
    address: Department, University
column_numbers: 3
logoright_name: https&#58;//raw.githubusercontent.com/brentthorne/posterdown/master/images/betterhexlogo.png
logoleft_name: https&#58;//raw.githubusercontent.com/brentthorne/posterdown/master/images/betterhexlogo.png
output: 
  posterdown::posterdown_html:
    self_contained: false
knit: pagedown::chrome_print
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# Intro

```{r table1, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = 'asis', fig.pos='!h'}
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

col_1 <- c(1,2,3)
col_2 <- c(4,5,6)
col_3 <- c(7,8,9)

data.frame(col_1, col_2, col_3) %>% 
  kable(format='html',booktabs=TRUE, caption = "This is the caption", escape=F) %>% 
  kable_styling(font_size = 45)

```

`````
``````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the title, you have several options. The easiest is certaintly to insert a `<br>` before the title in the YAML at the top of your document. This will insert a line return before your title.

Alternatively, you could insert a CSS block to alter the style of the `h1` tag:

````r
```{css, echo=FALSE}
h1 {
    padding-top: 40px
}
```
````

In principle, you should be able to include this kind of CSS block to change the style of any HTML element. However, `kableExtra` seems to hard code the font size and to ignore CSS, so this solution only works for *some* style elements. One hacky solution is to manually substitute the font size in the raw HTML using `gsub` or some other similar mechanism:

````r
```{css, echo=FALSE}
.table caption {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```{r table1, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, results = 'asis', fig.pos='!h'}
library(kableExtra)

col_1 <- c(1,2,3)
col_2 <- c(4,5,6)
col_3 <- c(7,8,9)

data.frame(col_1, col_2, col_3) %>% 
    kbl(format = 'html',
        escape = FALSE,
        caption = "This is the caption") %>% 
    kable_styling(font_size = 45) %>%
    gsub("font-size: initial !important;", 
         "font-size: 45pt !important;", 
         .)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Yes, that looks like a `kableExtra` bug:  "initial" would almost always be a bad idea.  Maybe that's supposed to be "inherited"?

Comment: BTW, the substitution in the caption font size in your answer is incomplete:  I think it should be something like `gsub("font-size: initial !important;", "font-size: 45pt !important;", .)`